# Instance rendering OpenGL

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, qt5

I am having a bad time trying to figure out why the call to **glDrawArraysInstanced** is drawing the correct number of instances but with wrong sizes of the objects.
Here's my code (class declaration ommited)

```
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLBuffer>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLShaderProgram>
#include <iostream>

const float OpenGLViewer::_quad[] = {
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.9f,  1.0f, 0.0f
};

const float OpenGLViewer::_offset[] = {
    0.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4
};

...

void OpenGLViewer::initializeGL()
{
    QGLFormat glFormat = QGLWidget::format();
    if(!glFormat.sampleBuffers())
        std::cout << "Could not enable sample buffers.";

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());

    if(!prepareShaderProgram(":/vertex.glsl", ":/fragment.glsl"))
        return;

    if(!_shaderProgram.bind())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not bind shader program to the context.";
        return;
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertexArraysObject);
    glBindVertexArray(_vertexArraysObject);         // BIND

    glGenBuffers(1, &_quadBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _quadBuffer);     // BIND
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_quad), _quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    //glVertexAttribDivisorARB(0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_offsetBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _offsetBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_offset), _offset, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribDivisorARB(1, 1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void OpenGLViewer::paintGL()
{
    // Clear the buffer with the current clearing color
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Draw stuff
    glBindVertexArray(_vertexArraysObject);

    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, 4);
}

...
```

What I'm trying to do is to draw the same rectangle but at different positions using the value of offset in the vertex shader. It is important to say that I am using **glVertexAttribDivisorARB(1, 1)** (note the ARB suffix) since in Qt+OSX Mavericks I cannot find the function **glVertexAttribDivisor**. Any thoughts?

The resulting image looks like

[image]

**EDIT**

Forgot to include the shaders

```
// VERTEX shader
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in float offset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.x + offset, vertexPosition.y + offset, vertexPosition.zw);
}

//FRAGMENT shader
#version 330

layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: and how do the shaders look like?

Comment: @ratchetfreak just edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.x + offset, vertexPosition.y + offset, vertexPosition.zw);
```

adding the offset to y moves it upwards (off screen)

you should either not add the offset to y or subtract it instead:

```
gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.x + offset, vertexPosition.y - offset, vertexPosition.zw);
```